# Uncaught TypeError: pJS_tag is null - ParticlesJS fails out of the box

Tags: javascript, html, particles.js

I'm trying to run Particles.Js with no modifications, and its failing out of the box with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: pJS_tag is null
```

I've installed it via npm install. Here is my HTML

```js
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
        <script src="/node_modules/particles.js/particles.js"> </script> 

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="particles-js"></div>
        <div class="banner">test</div>
    <script src= 
        "/node_modules/particles.js/demo/js/app.js"> 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to move the `particles.js` include before `<script src="/node_modules/particles.js/demo/js/app.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, I forgot to set the "id" field, and assumed "class" was good enough.

Example:
Change

```
<div class="particles-js"></div>
```

to:

```
<div class="particles-js" id="particles-js"></div>
```